# Variable number of repeating command in macros

Tags: macros, chemstyle

I am quite new to Latex and for the past few days I have been struggling to create a macro to insert schemes with labels. I use .eps files for my schemes which include a temporary marker that is then replaced with a number by the chemstyle package. The command is `\schemeref` and includes the temporary marker and a label (named cmpd...).
My macro works if there is just one item to label:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemstyle} 

\begin{document}

\newcommand\insertscheme[5]{%
  \begin{scheme}
    \schemeref[#1]{cmpd:#2}
    \includegraphics{#3}
    \caption{#4}
    \label{scheme:#5}
  \end{scheme}}

\insertscheme
{TMP1}{benzene}
{benzene.eps}{Structure of \compound{cmpd:benzene}.}{benzene}

\end{document}
```

[image]

However, I also have schemes which include more than one structure, usually between 2 and 7. Without the macro I can label all structures like the following example shows:

```
\begin{scheme}
\schemeref[TMP1]{cmpd:benzene}
\schemeref[TMP2]{cmpd:Brbenzene}
\includegraphics{benzene-Brbenzene.eps}
\caption{Structure of \compound{cmpd:benzene} and \compound{cmpd:Brbenzene}.}
\label{scheme:benzene-Brbenzene}
\end{scheme}
```

My question now: How do I need to change the macro so that it can be used for schemes with a variable number structures inside?

I am using the LaTeX compiler on Overleaf.

Comment: Does anyone know if there is a way to use the automatic numbering with the pdfLatex compiler on Overleaf?

Answer (score 6):

If all your calls to `\insertscheme` are of pattern

```
\insertscheme{⟨IDENTIFIER A⟩}%
             {⟨IDENTIFIER B⟩}%
             {⟨IDENTIFIER B⟩.eps}%
             {Structure of \compound{cmpd:⟨IDENTIFIER B⟩}.}%
             {⟨IDENTIFIER B⟩}%
```

, then you can instead define

```
\newcommand\insertscheme[2]{%
  \begin{scheme}%
    \schemeref[{#1}]{cmpd:#2}%
    \includegraphics{#2.eps}%
    \caption{Structure of \compound{cmpd:#2}.}%
    \label{scheme:#2}%
  \end{scheme}%
}
```

and do `\insertscheme{⟨IDENTIFIER A⟩}{⟨IDENTIFIER B⟩}%`.

Then you can define a macro `\insertschemes` which processes a list of comma-separated two-argument-tuples which works as follows:

```
\insertschemes{%
  {TMP1}{benzene},
  ...
  {TMP2}{Brbenzene},
}%
```

The macro `\insertschemes` in the example below, if called as

```
\insertschemes{%
  {TMP1}{benzene},
  {TMP2}{Brbenzene},
  {TMP3}{Fbenzene},
}%
```

, creates the tokens

```
\begin{scheme}%
\schemeref[{TMP1}]{cmpd:benzene}%
\schemeref[{TMP2}]{cmpd:Brbenzene}%
\schemeref[{TMP3}]{cmpd:Fbenzene}%
\includegraphics{benzene-Brbenzene-Fbenzene.eps}%
\caption{%
  Structure of \compound{cmpd:benzene} %
  and \compound{cmpd:Brbenzene} %
  and \compound{cmpd:Fbenzene}%
}%
\label{scheme:benzene-Brbenzene-Fbenzene}%
\end{scheme}%
```

for you.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemstyle} 

\usepackage{xparse} 
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l__my_insertschemes_clist
\tl_new:N \l__my_insertschemes_schemerefs_tl
\tl_new:N \l__my_insertschemes_compounds_tl
\tl_new:N \l__my_insertschemes_names_tl
\bool_new:N  \__bool_my_insertschemes_names_first_item
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__my_insertschemes_set_tls:nn {
  \bool_if:NTF \__bool_my_insertschemes_names_first_item {
    \bool_set_false:N \__bool_my_insertschemes_names_first_item
  }{
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__my_insertschemes_compounds_tl {~and~}
    \tl_put_right:Nn \l__my_insertschemes_names_tl {-}
  }
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__my_insertschemes_compounds_tl {\compound{cmpd:#2}}
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__my_insertschemes_names_tl {#2}
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__my_insertschemes_schemerefs_tl {
    \schemeref[{#1}]{cmpd:#2}
  }
}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__my_insertschemes_use_tls:nnnn{
  % If you want to see what this does, uncomment the following two comments:
  %\def\tempa{
    \begin{#1}
    #2
    \includegraphics{#3.eps}
    \caption{Structure~of~#4}
    \label{scheme:#3}
    \end{#1}
  %}\show\tempa
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__my_insertschemes_use_tls:nnnn {nVVV}

\NewDocumentCommand \insertschemes {m} {
  \group_begin:
  \clist_clear:N \l__my_insertschemes_clist
  \tl_clear:N \l__my_insertschemes_schemerefs_tl
  \tl_clear:N \l__my_insertschemes_compounds_tl
  \tl_clear:N \l__my_insertschemes_names_tl
  \clist_set:Nn \l__my_insertschemes_clist {#1}
  \bool_set_true:N \__bool_my_insertschemes_names_first_item
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l__my_insertschemes_clist {
    \__my_insertschemes_set_tls:nn ##1
  }
  \__my_insertschemes_use_tls:nVVV {scheme}
                                   {\l__my_insertschemes_schemerefs_tl} 
                                   {\l__my_insertschemes_names_tl} 
                                   {\l__my_insertschemes_compounds_tl}
  \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\insertschemes{%
  {TMP1}{benzene},
  {TMP2}{Brbenzene},
  {TMP3}{Fbenzene},
}%

\end{document}
```

If you need to process more than two arguments per argument-tuple, then all you need to do is to redefine `\__my_insertschemes_set_tls:nn` to process more than two arguments/identifiers.

---

---

Edit 1:

That was one of my first attempts to use expl3/LaTeX3.

**To be honest, I like [the approach of wipet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/577363/118714) much better:**

**His macros are short and are all expandable.**
**His approach is very resource-efficient, since no temporary assignments are made in any loop, such as defining temporary helper macros and the like.**
**And with his `\doscheme` you don't need to type so many curly braces. ;-)**

---

Edit 2:

Now that [wipet](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/577363/118714) has started the ball rolling, a variation of his code where in the very edge case of `\doscheme`'s 2nd argument being empty `\compounds` will not create a `\compound`-command in the 1st iteration:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemstyle} 

\def\doscheme[#1]#2{%
   \begin{scheme}%
   \schemerefs #1--;#2--%
   \includegraphics{#2.eps}%
   \caption{Structure of \compounds{}#2--.}%
   \label{scheme:#2}%
   \end{scheme}%
}
\def\schemerefs #1-#2;#3-{%
   \ifx^#1^\else\schemeref[{#1}]{cmpd:#3}\afterfi{\schemerefs#2;}\fi
}
\def\compounds #1#2-{%
  \ifx^#2^\else#1\compound{cmpd:#2}\afterfi{\compounds{ and }}\fi
}
\def\afterfi#1#2\fi{\fi#1}

\begin{document}

Tests:
\doscheme[TMP1]{benzene}
\doscheme[TMP1-TMP2]{benzene-Brbenzene}
\doscheme[TMP1-TMP2-TMP3]{benzene-Brbenzene-Rkbenzene}

\end{document}
```

---

---

If you don't wish the name of the image-file, the text of the caption and the name of the cross-referencing-label to be created automatically but wish them to be passed as arguments, the following code defines a variant of `\insertschemes` where

```
\insertschemes{%
  {TMP1}{benzene},
  {TMP2}{Brbenzene},
  {TMP3}{Fbenzene},
}{NameOfImageFile}{text of caption}{CrossReferencingLabel}%
```

delivers the tokens

```
\begin{scheme}%
\schemeref[{TMP1}]{cmpd:benzene}%
\schemeref[{TMP2}]{cmpd:Brbenzene}%
\schemeref[{TMP3}]{cmpd:Fbenzene}%
\includegraphics{NameOfImageFile.eps}%
\caption{text of caption}%
\label{scheme:CrossReferencingLabel}%
\end{scheme}%
```

, i.e., only the sequence of `\schemeref`-commands is created automatically:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemstyle} 

\usepackage{xparse} 
\ExplSyntaxOn
\clist_new:N \l__my_insertschemes_clist
\tl_new:N \l__my_insertschemes_schemerefs_tl
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__my_insertschemes_set_tls:nn {
  \tl_put_right:Nn \l__my_insertschemes_schemerefs_tl {
    \schemeref[{#1}]{cmpd:#2}
  }
}
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__my_insertschemes_use_tls:nnnnn {
  % If you want to see what this does, uncomment the following two comments:
  %\def\tempa{
    \begin{#1}
    #2
    \includegraphics{#4.eps}
    \caption{#3}
    \label{scheme:#5}
    \end{#1}
  %}\show\tempa
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__my_insertschemes_use_tls:nnnnn {nVnnn}

\NewDocumentCommand \insertschemes {mmmm} {
  \group_begin:
  \clist_clear:N \l__my_insertschemes_clist
  \tl_clear:N \l__my_insertschemes_schemerefs_tl
  \clist_set:Nn \l__my_insertschemes_clist {#1}
  \clist_map_inline:Nn \l__my_insertschemes_clist {
    \__my_insertschemes_set_tls:nn ##1
  }
  \__my_insertschemes_use_tls:nVnnn {scheme}
                                   {\l__my_insertschemes_schemerefs_tl}
                                   {#3}
                                   {#2} 
                                   {#4}
  \group_end:
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\insertschemes{%
  {TMP1}{benzene},
  {TMP2}{Brbenzene},
  {TMP3}{Fbenzene},
}{NameOfImageFile}{text of caption}{CrossReferencingLabel}%

\end{document}
```

Syntax where optional arguments of `\schemeref` are optional within the argument-tuples also can be achieved without expl3 - here the loop is carried out inside the scheme-environment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemstyle} 

\makeatletter
\begingroup
% \Removespaces removes one leading and one trailing space from its argument if present.
% Be aware that this implementation also removes a leading implicit space token like
% \@sptoken but does not remove a trailing implicit space token.
\def\Removespaces#1{%
  \endgroup
  \newcommand\Removespaces[1]{%
    % Let's have \romannmeral create a negative number from an alphabetic constant.
    % The negative number will not be printed by \romannumeral but things get expanded
    % while scanning for the <optional space> that is probably trailing the alphabetic
    % constant and that is also removed if present. (It will be present if the argument
    % of \Removespaces has a leading space.)
    \romannumeral-`\A\EnsureForbiddenBeforeTrailSpace\noexpand##1\UD@Forbidden#1\UD@Forbidden
  }
}\Removespaces{ }%
\@ifdefinable\EnsureForbiddenBeforeTrailSpace{%
  \long\def\EnsureForbiddenBeforeTrailSpace#1 \UD@Forbidden{%
    \RemoveTrailingForbiddens#1\UD@Forbidden
  }%
}%
\@ifdefinable\RemoveTrailingForbiddens{%
  \long\def\RemoveTrailingForbiddens#1\UD@Forbidden#2{#1}%
}%
\@ifdefinable\gobbledot{\def\gobbledot.{}}%
\@ifdefinable\schemerefloop{%
  \long\def\schemerefloop#1,{%
    \if$\detokenize\expandafter{\@secondoftwo#1{}}$%
    \expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi
    {\schemerefloop.}{%
       \expandafter\expandafter
       \expandafter\expandafter
       \expandafter\expandafter
       \expandafter\doschemeref
       \expandafter\Removespaces
       \expandafter{\gobbledot#1}%
    }%
  }%
}%
\newcommand\doschemeref{%
  \@ifnextchar[\doschemeref@opt\doschemeref@noopt
}%
\newcommand\doschemeref@opt[2][]{%
  \schemeref[{#1}]{cmpd:#2}\schemerefloop.%
}%
\newcommand\doschemeref@noopt[1]{%
  \ifx\schemerefloop#1\expandafter\@gobble\else\expandafter\@firstofone\fi
  {\schemeref{cmpd:#1}\schemerefloop.}%
}%
\@ifdefinable\insertschemes{%
  \DeclareRobustCommand\insertschemes[4]{%
     \begin{scheme}%
     \schemerefloop.#1,{\schemerefloop},%
     \includegraphics{#2.eps}%
     \caption{#3}%
     \label{#4}%
     \end{scheme}%
  }%
}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\insertschemes{%
  [TMP1]{benzene},
  {Brbenzene},
  [TMP3]{Fbenzene},
}{NameOfImageFile}{text of caption}{CrossReferencingLabel}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Minor nitpick on `expl3` conventions: variables should be named `\l__my_...` rather than `\__l_my_...`, and all your functions seem to be non-expandable, so you should use `\cs_new_protected:Nn` rather than the non-protected versions

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thanks for nitpicking. ;-)  I have edited my answer to take your remarks into account.

Comment: I agree, I like wipet's solution. How would I have to modify the code if I want to have a custom caption for each scheme and also use custom image names (with the current solution the image names will get very long for larger schemes)?

Comment: I just experimented a little: would it be correct to write `\def\doscheme[#1]#2#3#4{%` and write `\includegraphics{#3.eps}%` and `\caption{#4}%`?

Comment: @piggy Yes. If you don't wish arguments of `\includegraphics`-commands and `\caption`-commands to be created automatically but to be passed as arguments from `\doscheme`, then you can do this (and the `\compounds`-command is obsolete).  How do you wish the referencing-label to be created? Probably it is best you edit your question and describe exactly in which syntax you wish to enter things and what you wish to get in return in case of processing data of several structures.

Answer (score 5):

You can create a number of key-value options for `\insertscheme`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemstyle,graphicx,xkeyval}

\makeatletter
\define@cmdkey{fam}{scheme}[\empty@key]{}
\define@cmdkey{fam}{schemeopt}[]{}
\define@cmdkey{fam}{compoundAref}[]{}
\define@cmdkey{fam}{compoundAlabel}[\empty@key]{}
\define@cmdkey{fam}{compoundBref}[]{}
\define@cmdkey{fam}{compoundBlabel}[\empty@key]{}
% Add additional compound keys here...
\define@cmdkey{fam}{caption}[\empty@key]{}
\define@cmdkey{fam}{label}[\empty@key]{}

\newcommand{\insertscheme}[1]{{%
  \setkeys{fam}{%
    schemeopt=,
    %compoundAref=,
    compoundAlabel=,
    compoundBref=,
    compoundBlabel=,
    % Add additional compound key defaults here...
    label=,
    #1
  }%
  \begin{scheme}
    \ifx\cmdKV@fam@compoundAlabel\empty@key\else
      \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\schemeref[\cmdKV@fam@compoundAref]{cmpd:\cmdKV@fam@compoundAlabel}}\x
    \fi
    \ifx\cmdKV@fam@compoundBlabel\empty@key\else
      \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\schemeref[\cmdKV@fam@compoundBref]{cmpd:\cmdKV@fam@compoundBlabel}}\x
    \fi
    % Add additional compounds here...
    \ifx\cmdKV@fam@scheme\empty@key\else
      \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\includegraphics[\cmdKV@fam@schemeopt]{\cmdKV@fam@scheme}}\x
    \fi
    \ifx\cmdKV@fam@caption\empty@key\else
      \caption{\cmdKV@fam@caption}%
    \fi
    \ifx\cmdKV@fam@label\empty@key\else
      \expandafter\label\expandafter{scheme:\cmdKV@fam@label}%
    \fi
  \end{scheme}
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\insertscheme{%
  scheme=example-image,
  schemeopt={width=5em},
  compoundAref=TMP1,
  compoundAlabel=benzene,
  compoundBref=TMP2,
  compoundBlabel=Brbenzene,
  caption={Structure of \compound{cmpd:benzene} and \compound{cmpd:Brbenzene}.}
}

\end{document}
```

You could add additional compound keys `compoundCref`, `compoundClabel`, ... with additional setting within `\insertscheme` to suit your needs.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to use `\doscheme` macro wit syntax

```
\doscheme[TMPA-TMPB-etc.]{nameA-nameB-etc.}
```

which does:

- opens environment `scheme`
- does `\schemeref[TMPA]{cmpd:nameA}\schemeref[TMPB]{cmpd:nameB}` etc. in loop.
- inserts `nameA-nameB-etc.eps` picture.
- inserts capition `Structure of \compound{cmpd:nameA} and \cmpound{cmpd:nameB} and` ... (in loop)
- inserts label `scheme:nameA-nameB-etc`.
- closes environment `scheme`.

Example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemstyle} 

\def\doscheme[#1]#2{%
   \begin{scheme}
     \schemerefs #1--;#2--;%
     \includegraphics{#2.eps}
     \caption{Structure of \compounds #2--.}
     \label{scheme:#2}
   \end{scheme}
}
\def\schemerefs #1-#2;#3-#4;{%
   \ifx^#1^\else \schemeref[#1]{cmpd:#3}\afterfi{\schemerefs#2;#4;}\fi
}
\def\compounds #1-{\compound{cmpd:#1}\compoundsA}
\def\compoundsA #1-{%
   \ifx^#1^\else\space and \compound{cmpd:#1}\expandafter\compoundsA\fi
}
\def\afterfi#1#2\fi{\fi#1}

\begin{document}

Tests:
\doscheme[TMP1]{benzene}
\doscheme[TMP1-TMP2]{benzene-Brbenzene}
\doscheme[TMP1-TMP2-TMP3]{benzene-Brbenzene-Rkbenzene}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you, that is doing exactly what I wanted!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to take this route you can add `\protect` to make it work. (I would not recommend using macros with such excessive numbers of arguments, it is almost impossible to recall their usage, especially if you have several of them.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemstyle} 

\begin{document}

\newcommand\insertscheme[5]{%
  \begin{scheme}
    \schemeref[#1]{cmpd:#2}
    \includegraphics{#3}
    \caption{#4}
    \label{scheme:#5}
  \end{scheme}}

\insertscheme
{TMP1}{benzene}
{benzene.eps}{Structure of \protect\compound{cmpd:benzene}.}{benzene}

\end{document}
```